# What is the source of Xcode build settings defaults?

Tags: xcode, bitcode, xcodeproj, pbxproj

I have two Xcode projects. Neither of them have custom ENABLE_BITCODE setting `.pbxproj` file. But in one of them it's set by default to YES and in another one it's set to NO.
If I enable `Customized` filter - it's empty in both project.

Where the settings come from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see sources of particular settings by enabling Levels toggle in build settings.[image]

Comment: Thanks! Following this method I've found that ENABLE_BITCODE default value depends on SDKROOT setting